# How to pass the different temporary values to the triggered subroutine?

Tags: excel, vba

I have different workbooks of different people's profile, eg. John.xlsx, Isabella.xlsx, etc. I need to update these workbooks and save them. For eg. I update Age from 'ThisWorkbook.Sheets.("All_Routines")'. I have written a code called "FindMatch", which selects a workbook name from Column C in Sheets.("Profiles") and finds a match in Column A in Sheets.("All_Routines"). If the match is found then it runs a macro "Add_Age" from column B "Routines".

"Add_Age" subroutine should open the matched workbook. For eg. If John.xlsx is matched then it should open John.xlsx from the Workbook_path in Sheets.("Profiles"). After the workbook is opened, it should copy the Age and paste it in the John.xlsx workbook.

Similarly, I expect to open the Isabella.xlsx and other workbooks and do the same.

ThisWorkbook.Sheets.("Profiles")

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Workbook_Paths |  | Workbook_Name |
| 2 | C:\Workbooks\John.xlsx |  | John.xlsx |
| 3 | D:\New_Workbooks\Isabella.xlsx |  | Isabella.xlsx |

ThisWorkbook.Sheets.("All_Routines")

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Profile_Name | Routines | Age | Weight |
| 2 | John.xlsx | Add_Age | 24 | 60 |
| 3 | Isabella.xlsx | Add_Weight | 21 | 55 |

Final result in Workbook "John.xlsx"

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Profile_Name | Age | Weight |
| 2 | John | 24 | 60 |

Module "FindMatch"

```
Sub FindMatch()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, Sh As Worksheet
    Dim wsRws As Long, wsRng As Range, w As Range
    Dim shRws As Long, shRng As Range, s As Range
    Dim WBName As String
    Set ws = Sheets("Profiles")
    Set Sh = Sheets("All_Routines")

    With ws
        wsRws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        Set wsRng = .Range(.Cells(1, "D"), .Cells(wsRws, "D"))
    End With

    With Sh
        shRws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set shRng = .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(shRws, "A"))
    End With

    For Each w In wsRng
        For Each s In shRng

            If w = s Then Run s.Offset(0, 1).Value   
        Next s
    Next w
End Sub
```

Module "Add_Age"

```
    Sub Add_Age()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set WS1 = wb.Worksheets("Profiles")
    Dim c As Range, FoundCells As Range
    Dim firstaddress As String
    Dim Wrkbk As Workbook
    Dim wkbQuelle As Workbook
    Dim strDateTime As String
    Dim autOrdner As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim FinalFileName As String
    Dim tmpWB As Workbook
    
    Set tmpWB = ThisWorkbook
    Dim tmpSheet As Worksheet
    Set tmpSheet = tmpWB.Sheets("StandardPaths")
    
    
     
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Sheets("Profiles").Range("D1:D50")
        'find first cell that contains "rec"
        Set c = .Find("John.xlsx", LookIn:=xlValues)
        
        'if the search returns a cell
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            'note the address of first cell found
            firstaddress = c.Address
            Do
                'FoundCells is the variable that will refer to all of the
                'cells that are returned in the search
                If FoundCells Is Nothing Then
                    Set FoundCells = c
                Else
                    Set FoundCells = Union(c, FoundCells)
                End If
                'find the next instance of "rec"
                Set c = .Cells.FindNext(c)
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And firstaddress <> c.Address
                    
            'after entire sheet searched, select all found cells
           Set wkbQuelle = Workbooks.Open(FoundCells.Offset(0, -2).Value)
           wkbQuelle.Sheets(1).Name = ("Profile")
           
           'Example Copy Age
            ThisWorkbook.Range("C2").Copy
            ActiveWorkbook.Range("B2").Paste
           
    strDateTime = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yy") & " " & Format(Time, "hh-mm-ss")
     
     
    FolderPath = tmpSheet.Cells(3, 3).Value
            
    
    Filename = ("_" & ActiveWorkbook.Name)
    
    
   FinalFileName = strDateTime & Filename 
    
    wkbQuelle.Sheets(1).Columns.AutoFit
    Call FrontendStatus
    wkbQuelle.SaveAs Filename:=FolderPath & FinalFileName , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    wkbQuelle.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If
    
    End With
    
    End Sub
```

**What I have tried**

I tried to store a temporary value i.e the workbook name in a 'tempValue' As String and pass that value in 'Add_Age' subroutine. But, then the problem is either tempvalue is not passed in the Add_Age or if it is passed then I can't call the 'Add_Age' because the macro names becomes 'Add_Age(Byval tempValue As String)'. Any solution to achieve this? Thank you.

```
Sub FindMatch()
    Dim tmpValue As String
    For Each w In wsRng
                For Each s In shRng
        
                    If w = s Then Run s.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    tmpValue = s.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    
                Next s
               
            Next w


 Sub Add_Age(ByVal tempValue As String)
Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim wb2 As Workbook
        Dim WS1 As Worksheet
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        Set WS1 = wb.Worksheets("Profiles")
        Dim c As Range, FoundCells As Range
        Dim firstaddress As String
        Dim Wrkbk As Workbook
        Dim wkbQuelle As Workbook
        Dim strDateTime As String
        Dim autOrdner As String
        Dim FileName As String
        Dim FinalFileName As String
        Dim tmpWB As Workbook
        
        Set tmpWB = ThisWorkbook
        Dim tmpSheet As Worksheet
        Set tmpSheet = tmpWB.Sheets("StandardPaths")
        
        
         
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        With Sheets("Profiles").Range("D1:D50")
            'find first cell that contains "rec"
            Set c = .Find(tempValue, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your clarifications.  The following alternative uses `Public` declarations & provides you with the flexibility to add more routines as you go along.

You may need to add some error traps to make the code more robust - the following is provided as a guide to get you started with the rest.  Let me know how it goes.

```
Option Explicit
Public wb As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Public LastRow As Long, NewVal As Long
Public c As Range, d As Range
Public FileName As String, FullPath As String, Routine As String

Sub FindMatch()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Profiles")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("All_Routines")

LastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

If LastRow = 1 Then
    MsgBox "No records found"
    Exit Sub
End If

For Each c In ws1.Range("C2:C" & LastRow)
    FullPath = c.Offset(, -2).Value2
    FileName = c.Value2
    
    With ws2.Range("A:A")
        Set d = .Find(FileName, LookIn:=xlValues)
        Routine = d.Offset(0, 2).Value2
    
        Run d.Offset(0, 1).Value2
    
    End With
Next c

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "All routines completed"

End Sub

Sub Add_Age()
    NewVal = d.Offset(, 2).Value2
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FullPath)
    wb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 2).Value = NewVal
    wb.Close savechanges:=True
End Sub

Sub Add_Weight()    
    NewVal = d.Offset(, 3).Value2
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FullPath)
    wb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 3).Value = NewVal
    wb.Close savechanges:=True    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! 1st. The user uses a userform to select folders of workbooks and all the different paths are written in A:A in sheets."Profiles". Then from these paths, the workbook names are extracted and copied to C:C. So I can't keep the same path in const.   2nd. There are also different routines like "Add_weight", so I can't merge the 'FindMatch' and 'Add_Age' routines. Findmatch is suppose to find the different routines for different workbooks and run them. Please check the edits in my questions. Thank you

Comment: Understood. I'll delete my answer & provide an alternative soon. Can I ask, how many different routines do you have?

Comment: Currently, I have 15 different routines, but I want to maintain the flexibility to add more routines in the Sheets.'All_Routines'. Thank you once again!

Comment: Have you had the chance to test the amended code yet?  It worked for me with some test data, just wondered if it worked for you.

Comment: The code works perfectly! Thanks a lot for your support! Have a great time! :) :) :)